# How to select a value from options as per the HTML through Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, select, selenium-webdriver, display

I'm trying to change the value of a dropdown and facing problem while selecting the value from `<select>` tag and `<option>` tag.

This is HTML that i want to change.

```html
<form name="frmSearch" action="" onsubmit="return false;">
  <span class="seljs_title                            ">
    <input id="searchByInput91" name="searchBy91" type="text" readonly="readOnly" class="m-tcol-c" style="width: 110px;">
    <input type="hidden" name="searchBy" value="0" style="display: none;">
  </span>
  <select id="searchBy" name="" class="m-tcol-c" onchange="$('query').focus();" style="width:110px;display:none;">
    <option value="0">one</option>
    <option value="1">two</option>
    <option value="3">three</option>
    <option value="4">four</option>
    <option value="5">five</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" id="query" name="query" style="ime-mode:active" value="" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) {nhn.search.goSearch(event);clickcr(this, 'sch.bsearch','','',event)}"
    class="m-tcol-c border-sub text">
  <a href="#" onclick="nhn.search.goSearch(event);clickcr(this, 'sch.bsearch','','',event); return false;">
    <img src="https://cafe.pstatic.net/cafe4/hidden.gif" width="42" height="21" alt="검색" class="btn-search-green">
  </a>
</form>
```

I'm using Webdriver(Chrome).This is my code.

```
driver.find_element_by_name('frmSearch').find_element_by_id('searchByInput91').click()
```

This code makes me to click the dropdown and open the options. After that, when I use this code :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('searchBy'))
select.select_by_value('1').click()
```

OR

```
driver.find_element_by_id("searchBy").send_keys("two")
```

Error messages always come out.

```
ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible: Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated   
  (Session info: chrome=69.0.3497.81)   
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.41.578737 (49da6702b16031c40d63e5618de03a32ff6c197e),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)
```

what should I do?

Comment: Short answer: You cannot. That's the whole point of Selenium. If an user cannot do it (like when element is hidden), Selenium (by design) does not allows you to do that.

Comment: Does form become visible after you click on text input field?

Comment: Its look like once you start typing some value in textbox then it start showing the dropdown values as suggestion. Correct me if i'm wrong ?

Comment: I don't know how to reply each comments one by one, sorry.
what you mean that click on text input field? In my case, when i click arrow icon beside dropdown, i can see the values that i can chooose.

Comment: Additionally, when i click dropdown with mouse, the 'class' in the HTML <span class="seljs_title"> changes to <span class="seljs_title        sopen">. Does this induces problem?

Comment: The solution is in here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52156388/how-do-i-select-items-from-a-drop-down-box-in-selenium-using-python/52157900#52157900

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the *HTML* you have provided it seems that the `<select>` tag contains *style* attribute as **display: none;**. So you can use the following solution to select an option:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
# other lines of code
driver.find_element_by_name('frmSearch').find_element_by_id('searchByInput91').click()
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@class='m-tcol-c' and @id='searchBy']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].removeAttribute('style')", element)
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@class='m-tcol-c' and @id='searchBy']"))
select.select_by_value('1')
```

Comment: It's improper way to handle hidden elements. User won't modify HTML DOM manually via dev-tools to make element visible.

Comment: Sorry, but can you change [find_element_by_id('searchByInput91')] to [find_element_by_class_name('seljs_title')] for me? I don't know how to code 'xpath'. Thank you very much for help.

Comment: Oh! It works!!!!!!! i just change 'searchByInput91' to 'searchByInput952' that changes all the time when i enter. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Andersson Can you tell me why this method is improper way? What you mean "User won't modify HTML DOM manually via dev-tools to make element visible."?

Comment: @justin_sakong , it means that this doesn't simulate user-like behavior. If your script made for test, with above approach you might miss a bug

Comment: @Andersson, Now I get it. Thank for your support. But how can I solve this problem without remove 'Display:None'?. Your code which you answered only works when 'Display;None' is removed. Could you tell me how to do if you have much times? I'm learned a lot from you today, Thanks.