# How to select a dropdown using Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm trying to select `EU Odds` from the dropdown in this HTML:

```
<div id="user-header-r1">
            <div>
                <a class="user-header-fakeselect" onclick="ElementSelect.expand( 'user-header-oddsformat' , 'user-header-oddsformat-expander' )" id="user-header-oddsformat-expander"><span>UK Odds</span></a>
                <ul class="user-header-fakeselect-options hidden" id="user-header-oddsformat">
                    <li><a href="#" onclick="changeOddsFormat(1); return false;"><span>EU Odds</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" onclick="changeOddsFormat(2); return false;"><span>UK Odds</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" onclick="changeOddsFormat(3); return false;"><span>US Odds</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" onclick="changeOddsFormat(4); return false;"><span>HK Odds</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" onclick="changeOddsFormat(5); return false;"><span>MA Odds</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" onclick="changeOddsFormat(6); return false;"><span>IN Odds</span></a></li>

                </ul>
            </div>
            <div><label>Time:</label></div>
            <div>
                <a href="#" class="user-header-fakeselect" onclick="op.showHideTimeZone();ElementSelect.expand( 'user-header-timezone' , 'user-header-timezone-expander' , null , function(){op.hideTimeZone()} );this.blur();return false;" id="user-header-timezone-expander"><span>23 Aug 08:33, GMT +1</span></a>
            </div>


        </div>
```

I've tried following the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52157900/11277108) with the following code:

```
target = 'EU Odds'
self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("user-header-r1 > ul").find_element_by_xpath("./li[.="+target+"]").click()
```

But I get the following error:

```
Exception has occurred: NoSuchElementException
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"user-header-r1 > ul"}
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: `user-header-r1` is an id, not a CSS class, you are trying to find element by CSS selector, which doesn't exist. Try finding by `id`

Comment: Thanks. Tried this: ```self.driver.find_element_by_id("user-header-r1 > ul").find_element_by_xpath("./li[.="+target+"]").click()``` but got ```Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="user-header-r1 > ul"]"}```. As you can tell I'm really new to scraping so I might need baby steps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your element target having attribute with `hidden` value:

> ...<ul class="user-header-fakeselect-options hidden"...

So I think you need trigger from another element first before attack the element target, try following code:

```
#click this first
self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div#user-header-r1 > div > a#user-header-oddsformat-expander > span').click()

target = 'EU Odds'
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//ul[@id="user-header-oddsformat"]//span[text()="' +target +'"]').click()
```

Answer (score 1):

Expand dropdown and make `li` elements visible. `WebDriverWait` will wait for required element conditions, in your the case it's a visibility. To get element by text using xpath you need to use quotas `//li[.='Some Text']` in text:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
driver.get("..")

target = "EU Odds"
driver.find_element(By.ID, "user-header-oddsformat-expander").click()
wait.until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//li[.='" + target + "']"))).click()
```

Comment: I get the following error on the last line: ```Exception has occurred: TypeError
'str' object is not callable```

Comment: Typo with method arguments. Fixed

Comment: Thanks! Ended up using this as I was having issues with the accepted answer. The clickable element was not loading before that snippet tried to click it.

Comment: Spoke to soon! Seems to be intermittent - sometimes it selects ```EU Odds``` and sometimes it doesn't :( ```driver.find_element(By.ID, "user-header-oddsformat-expander").click()``` definitely selects the dropdown. If I step through ```wait.until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//li[.='" + target + "']"))).click()``` then it always selects ```EU Odds```. Strange as my understanding of that line is that Selenium is supposed to wait until it can select ```EU Odds```?

Comment: MAnaged to get round this by putting a ```while``` loop in that checks the right element has been selected or it reruns the selection code. Always manages to get it right after 2-3 attempts but definitely no consistency!

Answer (score 0):

To select the element with text as **EU Odds** you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "ul#user-header-oddsformat li:first-child>a[onclick^='changeOddsFormat']>span"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//ul[@id='user-header-oddsformat']//li/a[starts-with(@onclick, 'changeOddsFormat')]/span[text()='EU Odds']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Both of these time out sadly :(

Answer (score 0):

Form the HTML element, the element you are trying to select has an ID named
`user-header-r1` not a CSS class, try using `find_element_by_id('user-header-r1')`
Then if the element is found, then try using `find_element_by_tag_name('ul')` on the same search, like so:

```py
head_elem = self.driver.find_element_by_id("user-header-r1")
head_elem.find_element_by_tag_name("ul")
```

This will first scan the HTML tree for an ID of `user-header-r1` which is the first `div` then finds the `ul` element inside the `div`